# Adding a Skyscraper image using CSS to the 'edge' of a webpage

Tags: html, css, web

I have a site at www.mariodecristofano.com/vrtraining where I would like to add an image similar to what's found at http://www.veteransretreat.org.uk/managecontent.aspx?mta_dmd=welcome_to_veterans_retreat&object.id=10105.

I have the image, but how do I manipulate the CSS, which is here: http://www.mariodecristofano.com/vrtraining/css/style.css ?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: you know you can just look at the other site's CSS, right?

Comment: For future reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

if you resize the window you'll see the image is actually docked to the center, its just that the picture itself is very large and the graphic is designed to be right of the body.

so to reproduce:

- make large image
- factor in space for body, push your graphic to the right of the image
- css the image to center top of body with this css:

`background: url('/path/to/image') no-repeat center top;`

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the said site reveals:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../images/veterans-retreat-background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The `background-*` properties are of interest to you. You can also use `background-position: top right;` to right-align your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css attribute `right:0` (if you want it to the right edge, left top and bottom are also available attributes), first you must give your image an absoulte position though by the css attribute `position:absolute`.  Z index will determine what your page with be ontop of or under, the higher the z-index the higher up (as if it were getting closer to your face)

HTML:

```
<img class='SS src='path/skyScraper'>
```

css:

```
img.SS {
       position:absolute;
       right:0;
       z-index:2;
       }
```